# How can I limit a simulated aircraft's angle of attack?

Tags: control-engineering, aerospace-engineering, simulation

I am making an aircraft in a simulator (using JSBSIM). Note that I am not a professional.

The manual states that it is limited below certain calibrated airspeed to a certain positive angle of attack.

I have tried different schemes to make this work, but I have not been successful.

For example the simplest was to just freeze the elevator when the limit was reached. But in for example a loop, the alpha will increase even with frozen elevators as the plane goes through the loop.

Another was to use a feedback of the exceeded alpha with a gain into reducing the elevator actuation. But that makes the plane pitch jerk. It should be smooth.

I hope someone can help me out. I prefer a solution that does not use PID controller as they are a pain to calibrate. Block diagrams or text help is very appreciated.

Comment: Are you trying to build an autopilot, or simulate the plane's response to arbitrary human control inputs? A "pitch jerk" when you enter a stall isn't necessarily "wrong" - basically, the plane has just stopped flying and started falling out of the sky, and unless you take the correct actions to start flying again, the remainder of the simulation will be fairly short. Try googling for "stall recovery" to find out how pilots learn to respond to this situation.

Comment: I am trying to build an angle of attack limiter, that does not allow the pilot to command an angle of attack higher than a certain point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this by converting the stick input to a Nz value. I then subtracted alpha in a certain range from that Nz input. Then converted that to elevator deflection using a integrator comparing actual Nz to the input.

I also found out that in the real aircraft I am simulating a certain stick input correspond to certain commanded G-force, so in all, its a good solution.